# WRX Power Steering Engine Light

Tags: subaru, power-steering, impreza, wrx

I replaced my power steering pump in my 2006 WRX but it's playing up for some reason.

The power steering reservoir is boiling when the car is on, and the steering wheel is incredibly hard to move unless the accelerator is pressed even on idle. The power steering pump seems to work when the accelerator is pressed but it will whine very loud.

On idle when you move the steering wheel it won't whine. The check engine light came on as well

I've flushed the old power steering fluid and added some ATF

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Arte you sure the fluid is boiling? Is it that hot? It may just be air bubbles - have you bled the system? My car needs to have the wheels turned lock to lock a few times to get all the air out of the pipes and into the reservoir. Then you check the fluid level again.

Comment: @SolarMike Hey Mike, thanks for the response. I'm not sure if it's hot but if the reservoir cover isn't on it would start going all over the engine bay. I've spent the past 30 minutes to an hour turning the wheel back and forth and it's still not working. I've removed the old power steering fluid from the reservoir and topped it up with ATF.

Comment: You're sucking air into the system somewhere. Check the connections where you had to interrupt the fluid flow to replace the pump. You'll find a leak drawing air there some place If there was a leak on the high pressure side, you'd be seeing power steering fluid being sprayed all over the place.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks for the reply, I'll have a look tomorrow. What would cause the check engine light to turn on though?

Comment: If the light is on, there should be a code.  Find out what it is.

Comment: I believe the only CEL which would appear for the power steering is the if the pressure is off (high or low). If you have air in the lines, I'd suspect it would come back as being low. (There might be other PS codes, but this is all I can think of at the moment.)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Since it's not EPS the only code that would come up would be for the pressure switch. Looking through a DTC table doesn't yield a result though. So it's probably unrelated. IIRC PS switch DTCs don't set the MIL on most cars.

Comment: @Ben - Yah, maybe that's what I was thinking of ... :P ... Thanks :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I tried to bleed my system and did exactly as this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5D2hc0UAXYg                                                  However, when I crank the car no fluid comes out